# Php inserting just main category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

This code inserting main and sub categories.

```
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
        $cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
        echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$category->name.'</a>';
    }
?>
```

i want just main one category name.

Comment: Avoid setting headers when not necessary (paragraph text)

Comment: add some more code,this code only echos doesn't insert anything

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/ here, read about the usage of `get_the_category($id)`